I am having issues with the checkout, how to authorize API?
I am getting this error on the production side. But in VS Code I am not having this problem everything is working, when I push the site to production I am having the error. I am logged in but when I click check out it is asking me to log in again. I believe it has something to do with Kinde, but I am not sure how to fix this.
Access to fetch at 'https://coffeememories.vercel.app/api/auth/setup' 
(redirected from 'https://coffeememories.vercel.app/api/auth/logout? rsc=15o7e') from origin '
https://coffeememories.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't 
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If 
an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS 
disabled. 

Image of error
I have check the errors but I do not understand what it all means

The issue is likely related to domain configuration. You need to ensure your domain settings match between where the auth flow starts and where it ends.
For Vercel deployments, you should dynamically set your Kinde URLs in your next.config.js:
const nextConfig = {
   env: {
   KINDE_SITE_URL: process.env.KINDE_SITE_URL ?? `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`,
   KINDE_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL:
   process.env.KINDE_POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ?? `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}`,
   KINDE_POST_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL:
   process.env.KINDE_POST_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ?? `https://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/dashboard`
   }
  };

module.exports = nextConfig;

